# What is the max number of distinct token addresses can an EOA wallet contain?

Tags: wallets

What is the max number of distinct token addresses (for ERC20, ERC721 etc.) can an EOA wallet contain?

Comment: Do you mean Metamask, another wallet, or just the EOA account?

Comment: infinite, infinite

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of Ethereum an address has 160 bits, so there are at most `2^160` different contracts.

The [ERC 20 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) implicitly assumes that an address contains a single token, so an EOA can have at most `2^160` EIP-20 tokens.

There new standards like [EIP 1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155) that allows a single address to manage multiple tokens. An `id` of type `uint` is used to identify different tokens, so an EOA can have at most `2^256 * 2^160` EIP-1155 tokens.

In the future a new standard can be defined increasing even more. Also it is possible to define a new type of address.

Answer (score 0):

An EOA address can hold any number of tokens. There is no limit based on count of token or type(standard) of token.